# How to implement Server Name Indication (SNI)

Tags: c, ssl, openssl, sni

How to implement Server Name Indication(SNI) on OpenSSL in C or C++?

Are there any real world examples available?

Comment: Also see [Serving multiple domains in one box with SNI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22373332/serving-multiple-domains-in-one-box-with-sni) for some code examples and using `s_client` to test your server.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

On the client side, you use `SSL_set_tlsext_host_name(ssl, servername)` before initiating the SSL connection.

On the server side, it's a little more complicated:

- Set up an additional `SSL_CTX()` for each different certificate;
- Add a servername callback to each `SSL_CTX()` using `SSL_CTX_set_tlsext_servername_callback()`;
- In the callback, retrieve the client-supplied servername with `SSL_get_servername(ssl, TLSEXT_NAMETYPE_host_name)`.  Figure out the right `SSL_CTX` to go with that host name, then switch the `SSL` object to that `SSL_CTX` with `SSL_set_SSL_CTX()`.

The `s_client.c` and `s_server.c` files in the `apps/` directory of the OpenSSL source distribution implement this functionality, so they're a good resource to see how it should be done.

Comment: s_client.c and s_server.c are good examples. I am trying to implement SNI on a client who acts as a load generator(network) and hammers a server with http/https requests. And server already has server side SNI implemented.

Comment: Do the server calls hold up in a multithreaded context? It seems like the SSL_set_SSL_CTX is innately not threadsafe (i.e. if you have two different inbound connections with two different certs, youll have a problem).

Comment: @chacham15: One way to make it thread-safe is to allocate one `SSL_CTX()` per certificate, per thread (and always handle the same `SSL` and `SSL_CTX` objects from the same thread).  The other way is to set thread callbacks with `CRYPTO_set_id_callback()` and `CRYPTO_set_locking_callback()`, in which case OpenSSL will make the right calls to the locking callback to make `SSL_set_SSL_CTX()` thread-safe.

Comment: That's a very nice high-level write up, thank you! jww has illustrated exactly this approach with a code example in [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22375715/1613573). Could one or both of you please augment these answers with the issue raised in the comments regarding multiple threads? For example, how is `SSL_set_SSL_CTX` innately not thread safe? It seems to only affect the SSL connection specified in the first argument.

Comment: Do you know how I can implement SNI support on a server using boost::asio as a socket ? I can't find any example.. I also don't see how I can add multiple ssl context, as the ssl socket takes the context in the constructor