# PHP server-side SNI support

Tags: php, ssl, https, php-openssl

I read a lot of php manpages but only found information about SNI support in contexts - http://www.php.net/manual/en/context.ssl.php

Is it possible to obtain SNI send by browser when PHP is working as a server? Server is created using standard stream_socket_server() as described in eg. this post: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-socket-server.php#98616

Comment: Wait, so you're saying that you have an HTTP server *written* in PHP, that's accepting SSL requests?  Can you tell us why you'd do such a thing?

Comment: @Charles: transparent proxy server. I've a lot of servers written in pure PHP (but most of them are non-http). It's pretty good language if you know how to use it ;)

Comment: Good architects also know when to use a nail hammer, a sledgehammer, and a jackhammer for different jobs.  :)  PHP is the wrong tool for the job you're trying to make it do.  Further, it looks like [support would have to be expressly present at the C level](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5113333/168868) to get OpenSSL to support SNI server-side, and it's not clear how to expose that functionality to PHP sockets...

Answer (score 5):

### Yes, server-side SNI support is available in PHP >= 5.6

- Here's the [relevant commit <sup>github</sup>](https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/fad14e3180b17127496c95fe7f0a4b1ca4f36196) if you're interested.

**Example Usage:**

```
$ctx = stream_context_create(["ssl" => [
    "local_cert" => "/path/to/cert.pem",
    "SNI_server_certs" => [
        "domain1.com" => "/path/to/domain1.pem",
        "*.domain2.com" => "/path/to/domain2.pem",
        "domain3.com" => "/path/to/domain3.pem"
    ]
]]);
```

**Notes:**

- The `"SNI_server_certs"` SSL context option maps host names
  to appropriate certs should a client handshake advertise SNI
  capability.
- Prefixing a `*.` will utilize the matching cert if a client
  requests the primary host name or any subdomain thereof. So
  in the above example our *domain2.pem* will be used both for
  requests to *domain2.com* and *subdomain.domain2.com*
- The `"SNI_server_certs"` ctx option has no effect for client
  streams.
- SNI support is enabled by default as of 5.6 for both servers
  and clients. Servers must specify the `"SNI_server_certs"` array
  to actually use the SNI extension, though.
- If the `"SNI_enabled" => false` ctx option is also passed then
  the `"SNI_server_certs"` array has no effect.
- While supporting SNI by itself is enough to successfully
  negotiate the TLS handshake with many clients, servers MUST
  still specify a `"local_cert"` ctx option or run the risk of
  connection failures from clients that do not support the SNI
  extension.

**Prior to PHP 5.6 server-side SNI is not possible ...**

This is because encrypted PHP servers currently only use a single OpenSSL `SSL_CTX` C struct internally. Deploying SNI in a server requires a separate `SSL_CTX` for each individual certificate you wish to present.

**Other New 5.6 TLS Features**

There are quite a few SSL/TLS improvements for encrypted servers in the forthcoming PHP 5.6 release beyond SNI support. You can read about some of them here:

- [[RFC] Improved TLS Defaults](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/improved-tls-defaults)
- [PHP 5.6 NEWS file](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-5.6/NEWS)