# Serving multiple domains in one box with SNI

Tags: c, openssl, sni

I'm using OpenSSL 0.9.8q in FreeBSD-8.2. I have 3 virtual hosts on my system and want to implement SNI to serve for all 3 of them in one server.

I have 3 separate certificates one for each, and in my ssl-server code I have to somehow find out what is the domain-name of client's request, and use the appropriate certificate file based on that. For this I wrote a function named `get_ssl_servername_cb` and passed it as callback function to `SSL_CTX_set_tlsext_servername_callback`. This way, in callback function I can get the the domain-name of the client's request.

But my problem is, this callback function is being executed after execution of `SSL_accept` function, but I have to choose and use the appropriate certificate before using `SSL_new` command, which is way before execution of `SSL_accept`.

So my question is, how can I use `SSL_CTX_set_tlsext_servername_callback` function for SNI?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement Server Name Indication(SNI) on OpenSSL in C or C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113333/how-to-implement-server-name-indicationsni-on-openssl-in-c-or-c)

Comment: actually I read that thread, but the answer there wasn't clear enough for me, and I couldn't make it work with that.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. It is lite on information.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> but my problem is, this callback function is being executed after execution of "SSL_accept" function, but I have to choose and use the appropriate certificate before using "SSL_new" command, which is way before execution of SSL_accept.

When you start your server, you provide a default `SSL_CTX`. This is used for non-SNI clients, like SSLv3 clients and TLS clients that don't utilize SNI (like Windows XP). This is needed because the callback is not invoked in this situation.

Here are some examples to tickle the behavior using OpenSSL's `s_client`. To simulate a non-SNI client so that your `get_ssl_servername_cb` *is not* called, issue:

- `openssl s_client -connect localhost:8443 -ssl3` # SNI added at TLSv1
- `openssl s_client -connect localhost:8443 -tls1` # Windows XP client

To simulate a SNI client so that your `get_ssl_servername_cb` *is* called, issue:

- `openssl s_client -connect localhost:8443 -tls1 -servername localhost`

You can also avoid the certificate verification errors by adding `-CAfile`. This is from one of my test scripts (for testing DSS/DSA certificates on `localhost`):

```
printf "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n" | /usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl s_client \
    -connect localhost:8443 -tls1 -servername localhost \
    -CAfile pki/signing-dss-cert.pem
```

---

> so my question is, how can I use "SSL_CTX_set_tlsext_servername_callback" function for SNI?

See the OpenSSL source code at `<openssl dir>/apps/s_server.c`; or see [How to implement Server Name Indication(SNI) on OpenSSL in C or C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113333/how-to-implement-server-name-indicationsni-on-openssl-in-c-or-c).

In your `get_ssl_servername_cb` (set with `SSL_CTX_set_tlsext_servername_callback`), you examine the server name. One of two situations occur: you already have a `SSL_CTX` for the server's name, or you need to create a `SSL_CTX` for server's name.

Once you fetch the `SSL_CTX` from cache or create a new `SSL_CTX`, you then use `SSL_set_SSL_CTX` to swap in the context. There's an example of swapping in the new context in the OpenSSL source files. See the code for `s_server.c` (in `<openssl dir>/apps/s_server.c`). Follow the trail of `ctx2`,

Here's what it looks like in one of my projects. `IsDomainInDefaultCert` determines if the requested server name is provided by the default server certificate. If not, `GetServerContext` fetches the needed `SSL_CTX`. `GetServerContext` pulls the needed certificate out of an app-level cache; or creates it and puts it in the app-level cache (`GetServerContext` also asserts one reference count on the `SSL_CTX` so the OpenSSL library does not delete it from under the app).

```
static int ServerNameCallback(SSL *ssl, int *ad, void *arg)
{
    UNUSED(ad);
    UNUSED(arg);

    ASSERT(ssl);
    if (ssl == NULL)
        return SSL_TLSEXT_ERR_NOACK;

    const char* servername = SSL_get_servername(ssl, TLSEXT_NAMETYPE_host_name);
    ASSERT(servername && servername[0]);
    if (!servername || servername[0] == '\0')
        return SSL_TLSEXT_ERR_NOACK;

    /* Does the default cert already handle this domain? */
    if (IsDomainInDefCert(servername))
        return SSL_TLSEXT_ERR_OK;

    /* Need a new certificate for this domain */
    SSL_CTX* ctx = GetServerContext(servername);
    ASSERT(ctx != NULL);
    if (ctx == NULL)
        return SSL_TLSEXT_ERR_NOACK;   

    /* Useless return value */
    SSL_CTX* v = SSL_set_SSL_CTX(ssl, ctx);
    ASSERT(v == ctx);
    if (v != ctx)   
        return SSL_TLSEXT_ERR_NOACK;

    return SSL_TLSEXT_ERR_OK;
}
```

In the code above, `ad` and `arg` are unused parameters. I don't know what `ad` does because I don't use it. `arg` can be used to pass in a context to the callback. I don't use `arg` either, but `s_server.c` uses it to print some debug information (the `arg` is a pointer to a `BIO`s tied to `stderr` (and a few others), IIRC).

---

For completeness, `SSL_CTX` are reference counted and they can be re-used. A newly created `SSL_CTX` has a count of 1, which is delegated to the OpenSSL internal caching mechanism. When you hand the `SSL_CTX` to a `SSL` object, the count increments to 2. When the `SSL` object calls `SSL_CTX_free` on the `SSL_CTX`, the function will decrement the reference count. If the context is expired and the reference count is 1, then the OpenSSL library will delete it from its internal cache.

Comment: thank you for your perfect and complete answer. I managed to use SNI based on your answer. that was great :)

Comment: Thank you very much for all this! What should I make of the comment that is attached to the [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5113466/1613573) regarding thread (non-)safety of `SSL_set_SSL_CTX`? I have a multi-threaded server and would like to swap contexts exactly as you have shown. My server uses one thread per client connection, and each client can use a different host name. Hence, swapping of contexts can occur in any of the threads. Can changing the context in this way lead to any problems, i.e., in what sense can other threads be affected by this operation? Thank you very much!

Comment: I have now implemented SNI successfully, also based on your answer, so first of all, thank you very much for this detailed description and careful explanation! I am now looking into some of the details of your answer, and I think in your example, `GetServerContext` should **not** increment the reference count by one (as you say in the text): This will be done by OpenSSL in `SSL_set_SSL_CTX`. If your own `GetServerContext` also increases the reference count, you will have one too many. This can prevent OpenSSL from reclaiming the context when it is actually no longer needed. What do you think?

Comment: @mat - Its been a while since I worked with the code so I'm working from a fading memory... I seem to recall I needed to maintain a list of contexts. To know when I could remove the context from my list, I needed to keep a count. `SSL_CTX` will still be referenced counted By OpenSSL, and the OpenSSL counts are incremented and decremented as expected. However, you don't have access to the OpenSSL internal reference count, so you need to keep an external one.

Comment: OK I see, this is an interesting use case. What is currently at odds with this external count is the statement "so the OpenSSL library does not delete it from under the app". This cannot happen in this example (I think), and if it could, then increasing an external reference count could not prevent it, since OpenSSL would not know about it. I am not trying to nitpick on your excellent answer, I only want to ascertain that I get the details right, and simply add these considerations and discuss them a bit with you to clarify the somewhat more subtle aspects of your answer.

Comment: @mat - Yeah, my use case was an interception proxy, so OpenSSL server contexts could be reused for multiple clients. Feel free to make an edit once you get into your implementation. I'll be happy approve it.

Comment: Thank you, but I can impossibly edit this text, my companion during many hours of studying OpenSSL in the past few months ;-)

Comment: For a similar implementation samples, check out https://cpp.hotexamples.com/examples/-/-/SSL_set_SSL_CTX/cpp-ssl_set_ssl_ctx-function-examples.html