# Context for multiple connections with OpenSSL

Tags: c, ssl, openssl, connection

I want to get multiple connections with OpenSSL.

1. Should I create new `SSL_CTX context` for every new connection or accept all connections with one `context`?
2. Should I do additional actions with memory or something with start/stop connection, except

   ```
   close(_socket); //socket which accept the connection
   SSL_shutdown(_ssl); //_ssl — SSL connection
   SSL_free (_ssl);
   ```

Comment: Related, see [Does OpenSSL allow multiple SSL_CTX per process, one SSL_CTX used for server sessions and the other SSL_CTX for client sessions?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27649641).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Should I create new SSL_CTX context for every new connection or accept all connections with one context?

It depends on the number of server names and distinct certificates.

If you have one server name and one certificate, then use one default context.

If you have multiple server names and one certificate, then use one default context.

If you have multiple server names and multiple certificate, then see below on the SNI or servername callback and swapping in a context.

---

If your server listens for `foo.com` and `bar.com` with distinct certifcates, then you will need three contexts. One default context is for non-SNI clients, one context is for `foo.com`, and one context is for `bar.com`.

Effectively, the only thing that will likely change between the two sites is the certificate that's served. So you listen with the default context. *If* the client provided a servername via SNI, then you swap-in one of the other two contexts in the servername callback and `SSL_set_SSL_CTX`. Here's how it would look:

```
static int ServerNameCallback(SSL *ssl, int *ad, void *arg)
{
    UNUSED(ad);
    UNUSED(arg);

    ASSERT(ssl);
    if (ssl == NULL)
        return SSL_TLSEXT_ERR_NOACK;

    const char* servername = SSL_get_servername(ssl, TLSEXT_NAMETYPE_host_name);
    ASSERT(servername && servername[0]);
    if (!servername || servername[0] == '\0')
        return SSL_TLSEXT_ERR_NOACK;   

    /* Need a certificate and context for this domain */
    SSL_CTX* ctx = GetServerContext(servername);
    ASSERT(ctx != NULL);
    if (ctx == NULL)
        return SSL_TLSEXT_ERR_NOACK;

    /* We should not be peeking into the object like this... */
    ASSERT(ctx != ssl->ctx);

    /* Useless return value */
    SSL_CTX* v = SSL_set_SSL_CTX(ssl, ctx);

    return SSL_TLSEXT_ERR_OK;
}
```

`GetServerContext` just provides the context for `foo.com` or `bar.com`. It creates them once, and then reuses the same ones.

For the default context, you set the servername callback with `SSL_CTX_set_tlsext_servername_callback`. There's no need to set it for non-default contexts.

```
SSL_CTX_set_tlsext_servername_callback(ctx, ServerNameCallback);
```

Contexts are referenced counted, so you can reuse them.

---

> Should I do additional actions with memory or something with
>   start/stop connection, except
>
> ```
> close(_socket); //socket which accept the connection
> SSL_shutdown(_ssl); //_ssl — SSL connection
> SSL_free (_ssl);
> ```

Here, you should seek a treatment of the subject. For example, you should not call `close` before `SSL_shutdown`. And the first call to `SSL_shutdown` may fail, so you need to know what to do next.

For a treatment of the subject, see Eric Rescorla's tutorials: [An Introduction to OpenSSL Programming, Part I of II](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/4822) and [An Introduction to OpenSSL Programming, Part II of II](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/5487). Or get the book: [Network Security with OpenSSL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/059600270X).

Comment: I am getting this error: 'GetServerContext' was not declared in this scope

Comment: @udit043 - you have to write it yourself. It selects a certificate for a domain.

Comment: thanks, I have just started working on this field that's why I am not aware :)