# OpenSSL decryption failed or bad record mac boost::asio

Tags: c++, ssl, boost, openssl, boost-asio

I'm writing a transparent intercepting HTTPS capable proxy using boost::asio + openSSL. I have a default server context where I specify that the server is a TLSv1.2 server, when a client connects, I extract the host from the hello and use `SSL_set_SSL_CTX` to set the context (which either already exists or I've just created it after spoofing the upstream cert) and initiate the server (downstream) read/write volley as well as the upstream.

This was working before I started storing and sharing contexts. On each new incoming connection, I was creating a new client socket and context, loading ca-bundle as verify file, then creating a new server context, getting the spoofed certificate. It was functioning, but I started developing issues where EC_KEY objects were being double freed and such. [I learned from another question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29465501/ssl-use-certificate-seems-to-be-causing-a-double-free) that I was going about this the wrong way and began refactoring to recycle and share CTX objects. To be specific, I'm using a single client CTX shared across the board that loads, at program startup, the CA-Bundle for verification.

However, since this refactor, I'm getting this on both the client and the server:

```
 decryption failed or bad record mac
```

..mixed with a bajillion "short read"s. If I try to force everything TLSv1.2, I get

```
block cipher pad is wrong
```

Those errors are given to me after a read/write has failed and I call `async_shutdown` on either upstream or downstream sockets, which in the callback, error is set (so the shutdown failed).

I've scoured the interwebs finding jira posts from places like apache httpd and nginx where this error was fixed in different ways (resizing read buffers to be larger, openSSL patches, forcing SSLv3, so on and so forth).

I thought there might be an issue with multithreading (my io-service uses a thread pool) but I can see in the code that boost do_init sets locking mechanics for openSSL and all of my IO are wrapped into a single strand.

I'm at a total loss and am wondering if anyone can shed light on what might be happening. I realize I've posted no code, that's because I've got hundreds and hundreds of lines of it and don't want to turn people off with a huge code dump. I realize however this is a rather complicated program and thus a complicated issue so please ask and I'll provide whatever I can.

**Edit** 
I guess I should mention for completeness that I'm getting these errors on both openssl 1.0.2 and 1.0.2a, Win 8.1 x64 and I'm intercepting and routing the http/https traffic through my proxy with with WinDivert.

**Edit 2**
Reduced entire program to 1 thread, same effect. Created new client CTX for each client connection, same issue. Tried disabling AES-NI, issue persists. Tried different computer, same effect. Recompiled openssl from source (was using precompiled binaries), issue persists. Tried setting additional OP_ workaround flags described in current docs related to downgrade detection, padding bugs, so on and so forth, issue persist. I think I'll just start randomly mashing the keyboard and compile button soon.

Comment: You can have concurrency issues with a single thread, particularly if you use co-routines. The thread checks something, does something that implicitly or indirectly yields and allows another thread to run, and then does something assuming the thing it previously checked hasn't changed. Does each SSL connection have an associated strand? Are all asynchronous operations that can trigger composed operations properly dispatched on the strand?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz yessir, they do have an associated strand and all async operations that access the connections are wrapped as well.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I fixed it, and it was the most absolutely ridiculous thing, the error codes from openSSL were masking the real issue which, when I went over the control flow ignoring them, turned out to be a failure in parsing the initial request, which, since no async_io op was fired to carry on the session, led to a premature shutdown of the sessions which caused boost error codes to aggregate the mysterious and yet (almost) entirely unrelated "decryption failed or....". Thanks for your help. Not sure if I should just can this question.

Comment: You can answer it yourself I guess.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I was going to just delete this question, but I decided to answer it in light of the fact that nowhere on the net (that I could find) actually pointed to a correct solution to this problem. I've read every single report about this error that one could find and every single one of those reports, the people "solved" or "reduced" this error in a different way. Every single one of them, a different solution. This is what helped make this issue so difficult to reason out, because everyone everywhere has a different underlying causal explanation.

It's complicated, ready? This error will present itself if you cancel/abort a pending async SSL operation. Mind->boom(). It'll be even more confusing if you do what the docs say and use async_shutdown to do so, because even the call back to async_shutdown will fail (error code is set) and your error message will randomly be something stupid like "decryption failed or bad record mac" or "block cipher pad is wrong" or "SSLv3 alert!" so on and so forth. ***When seeing errors like this, ignore the errors and analyze the control flow of your IO ops, somewhere you're either prematurely ending them or getting them out of order.***

In my case, the premature end was (sort of) intentional, since during this stupid heavy refactor I decided to change things outside the scope of the problem, like my HTTPHeader parser, which I bugged out and ended up cause it to fail nearly 100% and thus aborting the connections. :) The error strings were masking the real cause by telling me encryption failed for some reason or another.  Dumb mistake I know, but I take comfort in being the first one (apparently) to recognize it. :)

Comment: I know this is old, but I am suffering the same issue when I am doing: ssl_do_handshake, its turning SSL_ERROR(1), and this exact issue.  Using 1.0.2l.

Answer (score -1):

Open a powershell and type this

```
(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri status.dev.azure.com).StatusDescription
```

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/deprecating-weak-cryptographic-standards-tls-1-0-and-1-1-in-azure-devops-services/