# what is the use of SSL_set_ssl_method after we have already created context using SSL_CTX_new

Tags: c, openssl, tls1.2

I am working on a SSL client server application. I want to enable all protocols above TLSv1 so what i am doing is

```
1)sslctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_method());
2)SSL_CTX_set_options(sslctx,SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2|SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3|SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1);
3)SSL_set_ssl_method(ssl,TLSv1_2_method());
```

The doubt that i have is will i also be able to connect using TLSv1_1 if i use TLSv1_2_method in SSL_set_ssl_method or will it only support TLSv1_2?

I want to support everything above TLSv1?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also see [Setting up TLS1.2 connection which supports SNI](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24415607/608639). Though its tagged with iOS, it applies to nearly all OpenSSL. However, it only answers your "TLS 1.0 and above" question. Its doe snot answer your "purpose of SSL_set_ssl_method" question.

Comment: Also, the TLSv1.1 client connection is easy enough to test: `openssl s_client -connect <hostname>:<port> -tls1_1 -servername <hostname>`. The `-servername` ensures you are using SNI. See [`s_client` man page](http://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/s_client.html) for details on the options.