# SNI (Server Name Indication) on OS X or iOS - NSURLSession CFNetwork

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, certificate, sni

I need to implement `SNI` (Server Name Indication) on client side for iOS and OS X.
I tried google about this but I was unable to find anything useful (only some instruction for [openSSL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5113466/1387438)). Nothing related to `NSURLSession` or `CFNetwork`.

I need solution when using both `NSURLSession` or `CFNetwork` (`CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost` - this is used in Socket Rocket).

Is it automatically supported by Apple framework? Or do I need add some extra code to enforce it? Or maybe it is completely unsupported?

Comment: If it is supported by Safari then take a look on WebKit how they do it. This is a tip, not a solution.

Comment: thanks, this is some starting point. I will also use wireshark with my application to see if it is supported out of the box.

Comment: I've checked my application with wireshark and it looks like that SNI is always active for free when using `CFNetwork`.

Answer (score 0):

SNI is supported on iOS. If you specify the `kCFStreamSSLPeerName` value in `kCFReadStreamPropertySSLSettings` of your `CFReadStream`, it will be used as the server name during the TLS handshake.