# get SNI from ssl client in C

Tags: c, ssl, sni

i,m trying to implement SSL client and server in C and i followed the link bellow
 https://aticleworld.com/ssl-server-client-using-openssl-in-c/
the code works and i am trying to print SNI (server name indicator) in my output generated by server (the client code is changed to send SNI) and i,m having problems with the server code
i looked around and found this
[How to implement Server Name Indication (SNI)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113333/how-to-implement-server-name-indication-sni)
but i cant follow it (too complicated for me)
i also read the code in openssl source dist (s_server.c) but i did not understand it
is there any straightforward way to just retrieve this value without going through all the callbacks and other stuff
pls consider server.c code in the first link

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: *"but i cant follow it (too complicated for me)..."* - sorry for you, but the way shown in this answer is still the way you need to go. I'm closing it as duplicate since your lack of understanding does not mean that you ask the same thing again.