# fake Server Name indication (SNI) in libcurl with OpenSSL backend

Tags: c, openssl, libcurl

I have libcurl built with OpenSSL backend. I want to set SNI to some specified string. the way that I could find is using the function `SSL_set_tlsext_host_name` which takes the `SSL *` instance and a string and then sets it. (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/5113466/3754125)

However curl_easy does not have a call back to retrieve `SSL*` instance. Is there an alternate way to do so?

Some more context:
In my environment, I have to use `CURLOPT_RESOLVE` to resolve the FQDN to IPv4.
There is the FQDN: `const char *fqdn`
IPv4 which `fqdn` should resolve to: `uint32_t ipv4`
fake SNI: `const char *sni`
The gist looks something like:

```
CURL *ez;
char buf[ENOUGH];
struct curl_slist *resolver;
/* ... */
snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%s:%d:%d.%d.%d.%d", fqdn, port, IP(IPv4));
resolver = curl_slist_append(NULL, buf);
curl_easy_setopt(ez, CURLOPT_RESOLVE, resolver);
```

After this I need to set the SNI to the fake SNI without touching the resolver.

Comment: `SSL_CTX_set_tlsext_servername_callback` might work. I'll update if it works.

Comment: If it works then please do answer the question yourself :)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala, unfortunately, my solution did not work. It only works for the server but in my case, I am the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to "fake" the SNI then `CURLOPT_RESOLVE` or `CURLOPT_CONNECT_TO` are available options to reach the same end goal.

## CURLOPT_RESOLVE example

Run a HTTPS server on 127.0.0.1 but make curl think it is `example.com` when it connects to it (so it sends that as SNI and in the `Host:` header)

```
CURL *curl;
struct curl_slist *host = NULL;
host = curl_slist_append(NULL, "example.com:443:127.0.0.1");

curl = curl_easy_init();
if(curl) {
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_RESOLVE, host);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://example.com");

  curl_easy_perform(curl);

  /* always cleanup */
  curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}

curl_slist_free_all(host);
```

## CURLOPT_CONNECT_TO example

Run a dev HTTPS server on the host name `server1.example.com` but you want curl to connect to it thinking it is the `www.example.org` server.

```
CURL *curl;
struct curl_slist *connect_to = NULL;
connect_to = curl_slist_append(NULL, "www.example.org::server1.example.com:");

curl = curl_easy_init();
if(curl) {
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CONNECT_TO, connect_to);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.example.org");

  curl_easy_perform(curl);

  /* always cleanup */
  curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}

curl_slist_free_all(connect_to);
```

Comment: How would one precisely do it with `CURLOPT_RESOLVE` or `CURLOPT_CONNECT_TO`? I am already using `CURLOPT_RESOLVE` to resolve FQDN to IPv4.

Comment: Thanks for including the code in your answer. However, this does not work for me. I am using `CURLOPT_RESOLVE` to resolve FQDN to IPv4 (looks like `curl_slist_append(NULL, "www.example.org:10443:172.18.27.161")`) (I have to do this because I have a specific API to resolve FQDN to IPv4 otherwise curl cannot resolve). The string that I am trying to inject into SNI is actually a token which the server uses to identify how it should dispatch the connection. The token looks like something like this: `tYqxjS6ntrqmPtBwUli1`. So If I want to fake SNI with `CURLOPT_RESOLVE` I cannot resolve the fqdn!

Comment: Okay, but then you're not doing HTTPS anymore... nothing wrong in that, but curl is focused on talking the specific protocols we've made it support.

Comment: Actually I am doing https! It is something like `curl_easy_setopt(ez_h, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.example.org:10443/api/entry/point")`. Are you implying that I cannot fake SNI in https?

Comment: On second thought on this solution, it worked for my case. `ipv4=getipv4(fqdn); snprintf(resolve_entry, sizeof(resolve_entry), "%s:%s:%d.%d.%d.%d", fake_sni, port, IP(ipv4)); resolve_list = curl_slist_add(NULL, resolve_entry);snprintf(url, sizeof(url), "https://%s:%s/%s", fake_sni, port, api_entry_point);` The only catch is that I had to set the referer to `fqdn`.