# What is correct way to implement multiple TLS certs and private keys for SNI rust web server?

Tags: ssl, rust, openssl, tls1.2, sni

With native_tls I see:

```
let ssl = ssl().expect("Failed to load SSL keys");
        let builder: native_tls::TlsAcceptorBuilder =
            native_tls::backend::openssl::TlsAcceptorBuilderExt::from_openssl(ssl);
        let tls_acceptor = builder.build().expect("Failed to build TLS acceptor");
```

Which I think has:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication

and:

https://docs.rs/native-tls/0.2.3/native_tls/struct.TlsConnectorBuilder.html#method.use_sni

use_sni is true by default.

But I'm still looking for correct way to load up N certs for N different domains and run all from the same server on same 443 port.

Is there way to call `TlsAcceptorBuilderExt::from_openssl(ssl)` over and over with N certs?

Edit1: found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5113466/148736) which explains a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Perfect example here: https://github.com/nikelmwann/garbageproxy/blob/578e92d56fc410a58f0b93195aef52a47cfbe3fb/src/tls.rs#L55 this loops through N servers and adds each cert and key

Comment: The link is broken unfortunately. Could you paste the code here?